Singular values of a real matrix $A$ are moduli of its eigenvalues iff $A$ is symmetric or skew symmetric?
Let $A$ be a square real matrix. If $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \ldots, \sigma_n$ are the positive roots of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$ (i.e., they are the singular values of $A$) and $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, then what I know is the following: If A is symmetric or skew symmetric ($A=A^T$ or $A=-A^T$), then $\sigma_i=|\lambda_i|$, for all $i$. Do we have a converse? If no, what are the conditions under which it would hold?

It holds if $A$ is normal, and I think the converse is true if the singular values are distinct but I haven't checked.

A matrix is normal iff the modulus of the eigenvalues equals that of the singular values.  If a matrix is normal then it is unitariy diagonalizable which gives equality of eigenvalue modulus and singular values. On the other hand eigenvalue modulus agreeing with singular values implies the (Schur) inequality $\text{trace}\big(A^*A\big)\geq \sum_{k=1}^n \vert \lambda_k\vert^2$ is met with equality hence the matrix is normal

Thank you very much. I am new, so I do not know how to conclude the topic.
